# Swapping two integers using pointers

Tags: c

I am trying to swap the value of two integers using pointers, see code below:

```
void swapArgs(int *a, int *b) {

    int *temp = &b;                                         
    b = &a;                                             
    a = &temp;                                              
    printf("Swapped Arguments: A=%d, B=%d\n", *a, *b);          
}
```

When the printf is executed, the resulting values are huge numbers.  Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code?  Still new to pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to copy the values, not the pointers:

```
int temp = *b;
*b = *a;
*a = temp;
```

**Note:** Your code is assigning pointers of wrong type - `&a` is `int**`, while `b` is `int*` (i.e. the number of asterisks does not match). Your compiler should have given you warnings about that. Fixing them would fix the problem.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  So my problem was that I was assigning integer variables to be equal to addresses, and not actual values?

Comment: @Froobyflake Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: I enjoy while reading your answers dear connoisseur @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your `a` and `b` are already pointers - so inside the function you must not use the `&` (address operator), instead you must use the `*` (dereference operator):

```
int temp = *b; 
*b = *a;                                             
*a = temp;
```